# Kotlin RxJava Room insert Observable

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

I'm trying to combine Room db with rxjava. It's ok with @query but error with @Insert

```
 @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAll(list: Observable<List<Film>>)
```

and error:

```
java:11: error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
```

Film data class:

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(
    tableName = TABLE_NAME,
    indices = [Index(value = [PAGE_NAME, CATEGORY_NAME, TITLE_NAME], unique = true)]
)
data class Film(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = PAGE_NAME) val page: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = CATEGORY_NAME) val category: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = TITLE_NAME) val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = POSTER_PATH_NAME) val poster: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = DESCRIPTION_NAME) val description: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = RATING_NAME) var rating: Double,
    var isInFavorites: Boolean = false) : Parcelable
```

Comment: The class `Film` probably doesn't have the annotation `@Entity` applied to it, based on the error message. See the docs https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: It does, I added the code

Comment: AFAIK room allows rx only in in return types, not in param types.